# Increment database value with c# winform

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access

I want to happen is, in my windows form, I have a textbox that accepts numbers or gets a number from the previous form.. if the textbox detects that it is not empty, the value in my database which is 0, will automatically increment to 1.

So for example, the value of a field in my access is already 2, if the textbox detects that the user input the number "3" then in the ms access, it will become 5. How can I do that? Please help me. Below are my codes.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pv1))
            {
                string newline = Environment.NewLine;
                textBox1.Text += newline + Convert.ToString(pv1);
                textBox2.Text += newline + "F(x) Lighstick 1";
                textBox3.Text += newline + Convert.ToString(pv7);
                textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(pv15);
                textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(pv14);
                textBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(pv16);
}
```

in my database the fields aqty and atotal are 0. So when textbox1.text(pv1) has a value of 3 and texbox3.text(pv7) has a value of 5, then aqty and atotal will become 3 and 5.

Comment: I am confused.  I see code that records values from variables into textboxes, but I don't see where your attempt is to manipulate your database based on the values in the textboxes.  Can you show us that code and provide more details about what you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already know how to get data from Ms Access database, you can do the same way to update. Just change SQL `SELECT` statement to become `UPDATE` statement, add parameters properly, then execute the SQL update command. For example :

```
conn.Open();

string query = "UPDATE [table_name] SET [column_name] = [column_name] + ? WHERE id = ?";
var accessUpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
accessUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("new_value", textBoxNewValue.Text);
accessUpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", 123);
accessUpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

That SQL update statement above will update value of `column_name` to (current value + new value) for specific row that match `WHERE` clause (without `WHERE` clause, all rows in the table will be added with the same *new value)*.